# Is the design of the car carefully prepared or really done without any proper plan?

Tags: bad-chad-customs

In the TV show [*Bad Chad Customs*](https://m.imdb.com/title/tt9397406/), Chad is proud to say that he designs, modifies and builds the car "on the fly", right off his mind. At the start of a new project, the more we see is sometimes a blackboard with a very simple drawing. He uses this to present his vision of the project to his team. No detailed plan, no measures, no check-list, no numbers, nothing.

Many other shows, like [Overhaulin'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overhaulin%27) or [Fast n' Loud](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_N%27_Loud) have all that setup listed, explained and shown. Chip Foose's design drawing is even an important step of the process.

My research shows no evidence that it's part of the show to, kind of, "create a dramatic effect" (like: full design is made beforehand behind the scene but producers let the audience think it's not). I know some people work like that and do things right off the bat (I also often do, while programming). My question is: **is there any evidence (crew, producer, client, any kind of witness or interview or footage) that the design and building process are carefully laid out before it starts?** Or is it just "part of the magic"?

Comment: Judging by the IMDB reviews, it seems the quality of the final products might be a clue to the lack of proper planning.

Comment: @Luciano : might be, but these *'cars'* are still well received and people like them, so quality seems to be good (on a personal note, I don't like all of them, not my style, but many are great achievements though, some work of art).

Comment: I'm not judging artistic quality, but the comments seem to be about the engineering aspect - that seems to be quite bad from what is visible in the show. That still might be prepared beforehand somewhat.